# Половинчатый radial.pie в R

Tags: graphics, r

Нужно нарисовать график типа "Пай чарт", только сектора должны располагаться не по кругу как на картинке, а по полукругу, то есть, все сектора на прямой линии.

```
library(plotrix)
xxx <- c(0.3000000, 0.4324350, 0.5186521, 0.6640783, 0.1140175)
radial.pie(xxx, show.grid = F)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно решить таким образом: добавить единичные значения в график и закрасить единичные сектора белым цветом :)

```
library(plotrix)
xxx <- c(0.3000000, 0.4324350, 0.5186521, 0.6640783, 0.1140175)
xxx1 <- c(xxx, rep(1, length(xxx)))
colors <- c(rainbow(length(xxx)), rep('white', length(xxx)))

radial.pie(xxx1, show.grid = F, clockwise = F, sector.colors = colors)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `fan.plot`, это наиболее подходящий вариант.

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/fan.plot

Пример:

https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/04/07/pie-charts-r/

```
parts <- c(22,65,10,3)
states <- c("New Jersey", "New York", "Pennsylvania", "Maryland")
fan.plot(parts,labels=states, align="left", max.span=pi)
```

[image: fan.plot]

Comment: Спасибо, этот график можно использовать как альтернативу. Но в идеале я хотел отобразить значения вектора относительной "высотой" этих кусков, которые в моем представлении должны были располагаться полукругом каждый с равными углами.